# Custom time and weekdays as Local Notification in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I have been struggling with Local Notifications and custom time and weekdays. I have a weekdays + date picker (just time in UI) and need to create repeating weekly notification depending on weekday and custom time. Let's say user wants to make reminder every Monday at 1:06PM. So I take data from date picker and make NSDateComponents from them, then I create fireDate and pass through method where is my notification. I always get just first notification but when I change time forward to next week in the same time, nothing happens. How can I ensure that this notification will repeat?

```
self.notification.time = self.datePicker.date;

//format hours
NSDateFormatter *hourFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
hourFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH";

//format minutes
NSDateFormatter *minuteFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
minuteFormatter.dateFormat = @"mm";

NSString *hour = [hourFormatter stringFromDate:self.notification.time];
NSString *minute = [minuteFormatter stringFromDate:self.notification.time];    

unsigned unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnitWeekday;

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponets = [calendar components: unitFlags fromDate:[NSDate date]];

dateComponets.weekday = 2; //Monday
dateComponets.hour = hour.intValue; //from date picker
dateComponets.minute = minute.intValue; //from date picker
dateComponets.second = 00;
dateComponets.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];


NSDate *fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponets];

//Create Notification
[self.notification scheduleNotification:@"HabitName" fireDate:fireDate alertBody:@"Alert Body"];
```

This is my notification method

```
-(void)scheduleNotification:(NSString *)habitName fireDate:(NSDate *)fireDate alertBody:(NSString *)alertBody
{

    self.note = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    self.note.alertBody = alertBody;
    self.note.fireDate = fireDate;
    self.note.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;
    self.note.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    self.note.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    self.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"test1" forKey:@"test"];
    self.note.userInfo = self.userInfo;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:self.note];

    NSLog(@"Notification set up for: %@", self.note);

}
```

Printed notification output:

```
Notification set up for: <UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x788d71c0>{fire date = Monday, December 7, 2015 at 1:06:00 PM Central European Standard Time, time zone = Europe/Prague (GMT+1) offset 3600, repeat interval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Monday, December 7, 2015 at 1:06:00 PM Central European Standard Time, user info = {
    test = test1;
}}
```

Comment: Solved! It did not work only on my Mac but in my iPhone it works perfectly.